# Git ignore not ignoring one file, but all files

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is the content of my .gitignore file

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

#Eclipse/Intellij
.classpath
.project
.settings/
target/
*.iml
.idea/
```

Basically all I want is to ignore the directory .idea and all the content in it. However, there is always one file that keeps popping up. I don't know why.

**civilization/.idea/workspace.xml**

This file keeps coming all the time, and I don't know why it doesnt get ignored!

Comment: because you already added it to the index?

Comment: or even commited it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore`only works for new files. If the file is already tracked you need to tell git not to do so any longer:

```
git rm .idea --cached
```

If you are not sure if files which are expected to be ignored are tracked or not, just remove all the files from the index and then add them back - git will use `.gitignore` when the files are being put back in the index.

```
git rm -r . --cached
git add .
```

Comment: Aaaah! Yes that indeed is the problem. I would thing it was smart enough to understand it should ignore it. Oh well. Now at least I know

Comment: After running rm git they are marked as deleted and git wants me to commit it. Guess thats fine...

Comment: @Shervin - Yes that's fine. Be sure to add `--cached` option, otherwise it will remove files from your working copy as well.